# Disadvantages of sending constant WOL packets?

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan

I'm using an old laptop as a home server, and it doesn't have anything in the BIOS for power recovery, so as a solution I have an Arduino setup to send WOL packets every minute. This way if the power goes out, the laptop will turn on automatically. However, when it is on (the majority of the time) it is still receiving magic packets. What are the risks of doing so (if any)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few packets every minute? That shouldn't be of any issue.

If you are worried, you could get the Arduino to ping the laptop and only send the WOL packet if it doesn't get a response.